# How to sort an array with parents and children objects with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with object, which I need to sort in a such way that first the parent object should appear, and then its children objects, and so on. However, when I try to find index of a parent object in array in order to push the children object after it, the findIndex() method returns -1. Can somebody point to the root of this problem, as I cannot clearly see why it does that.
The code and data array that I'm using is written below.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "_id": "0",
        "parent": null,
        "title": "All"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2d",
        "parent": null,
        "title": "Electronics"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2e",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2d" },
        "title": "Phones"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2f",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2d" },
        "title": "Laptops"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb30",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2d" },
        "title": "TVs"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb31",
        "parent": null,
        "title": "Literature"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb32",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb31"},
        "title": "Study Literature"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb33",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb31" },
        "title": "Fictional Literature"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb34",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb31" },
        "title": "Comic books"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb35",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb2e" },
        "title": "Smartphones"
    }, {
        "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb36",
        "parent": { "_id": "61c0a9cb8f67e811d55abb35" },
        "title": "Accessories"
    }
];


let parents = [];

data.forEach( element => {
    if( element.parent == null ) {
        parents.push(element);
    }
    else {
        let parentId = element.parent._id;
        let index = parents.findIndex(item => {
            item._id == parentId;
        });
        console.log(index);
        parents.splice(index+1, 0, element);
    }
});
```

Comment: What does your expected result look like? Nested arrays for the children or just a single array?

Comment: Expected output is just a single array.

Comment: Now you changed to using `indexOf()` but it works very differently than `findIndex()` and is not applicable to this situation of array of objects

Comment: Do the children need to immediately follow their specific  parent or just have all parents then all children?

Comment: Thank you very much! Replaced it with findIndex and now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `item => {parentId == item._id;}` does require a 'return' to be used: `item => {return parentId == item._id;}` without the return the function is basically `item => null`; which is than seen as false by `.findIndex()` resulting in a -1

If you use the arrow function without the curly braces a return is implied (But limits you to single line expressions as a trade-off): `item => parentId == item._id`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I changed the code based on your comment, but nothing changed.

Comment: @AlenIchshanov Strange did you change `let index = sortedData.findIndex(item => { parentId == item._id;});` to `let index = sortedData.findIndex(item => { return parentId == item._id; });` ?

Comment: Yeah, now it works, thank you! The other problem was that I tried to use indexOf() instead of findIndex().

Comment: @AlenIchshanov Ah you changed your code snipped; currently it is still in error (parents.splice(...) should be sortedData.splice(...). You might want to change the snipped back to the original state (when first asked the question); or  people might get confused how the answer related to the question and/or keep sending answers/questions